# Drop down menu from multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

This is an addition to the previous questions I asked. In my drop down box for engravers I would like the box to collect the surnames from three fields, Engraver1Surname, Engraver2Surname and Engraver3Surname. I also want each name only to appear once and to be in alphabetical order. My code doesn't work which means I've got it wrong again. This stuff is really challenging and I'm loving it but I don't want to be a serial pest.This is what I tried.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Engraver1Surname, Engraver2Surname, Engraver3Surname FROM engravers Where Engraver1Surname, Engraver2Surname, Engraver3Surname <> '' AND  Engraver1Surname, Engraver2Surname, Engraver3Surname IS NOT NULL ORDER by Engraver1Surname, Engraver2Surname, Engraver3Surname";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<select name\\='Engraver1Surname'>";
      echo "<option value='$_POST'>Engraver</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Engraver1Surname'] . "'>" .$row['Engraver1Surname'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";
```

Comment: You only seem to echo Engraver1Surname, don't you want to echo all?

Comment: Thanks Simon. I fixed that but still getting a blank sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name=array('Engraver1Surname','Engraver2Surname','Engraver3Surname');

$option=array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      for($x=0;$x<3;$x++){
      $option.=$row[$name[$x]];
      }

}

asort($option);

for($y=0;$y<sizeof($option);$y++){
echo "<option value='" . $option[$y]. "'>" .$option[$y] . "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Hope it fix to your question

Comment: Thanks Deeper. I don't seem to be able to get this to work. Are there values that I should be substituting in my code for x or y for instance?

Comment: for the x and y is just a instance variable for loop, from my suggestion, $option are used to stored 3 field per row while fetching.  Have you check the $option variable have contain all data ?

Comment: if the $option variable still remain empty data, you might check the sql fetch.

Comment: I'm sorry but this still seems to be going over my head. I'll go back a bit.Do I add this code to the code I already have or does it stand alone. I've been trying various combinations as your code ends with </select> which means I must at least need the select  line. With a combination, I get a box with engraver written in it but no names. I should post what I ended up with. Please don't laugh - oh, all right, have a good laugh if you like. I hope to myself one day.